# Strange CSS pseudo / Chrome behaviour

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am experiencing a strange behaviour of the CSS pseudo element ::before. It's applied to a container div (position relative / parent div) and has a static position (px) but it behaves as a % based position when scaling the window. (see image 1)

When using the Developer Console of Chrome the placement of the element is exactly as I expected to be placed. It's is just not render there. (see image 2) Sometimes it even renders twice.

The code is fine, works on other pages and no other browsers have issues with it. Just this page. See: https://jsfiddle.net/qedx9nju/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mod-form__container mod-form__container--email" ng-if="!lead.step || lead.step == 3">
  <label class="mod-form__label" for="email">Email</label>
  <input class="mod-form__input"
  ng-model="lead.email"
  id="email"
  name="email"
  placeholder="Hierop ontvang je de leads"
  type="email"
  ng-class="{ 'error': (quoteForm.email.$invalid && (quoteForm.email.$touched || quoteForm.$submitted)) }"
  nk-email required="">       
</div>
```

**LESS:**

```
.mod-form {

&__container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;

&::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  z-index: -1;
}

&::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  z-index: -1;
}

&--email {
  position: relative;

&::before {
  content: '\f0e0';
}

& input {
  padding-left: 38px;
}
}
}

&__label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

&__input {
  border: 2px solid #C4C4C4;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: transparent;

&::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
&::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
&:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}
&:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #C4C4C4;
  font-size: 14px;
}

}

}
```

#### Images

[image: Element behave strangly]
[image: Rendering issues]

Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 - MacOS

Question: What can cause this behaviour? Or how can I debug this?

Comment: ::before is creating the icon element before the input, so it is absolutely positioned to the parent element

Comment: @Leon, that's simply not true. It's positioned relative to the closest ancerstor with a `position` value other than `static` (which is default). So to make it relative to the input, since `<input>` is an orphan tag and cannot have `::before`. one needs the input in a parent with `position:relative` and the `::before` has to be on that parent.

Comment: It looks to work correctly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/qedx9nju/1/). So I guess you have stronger CSS interfering in your live code. Please reproduce the problem in a [mcve].

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yeah, it also works correctly on other browsers and even on other pages. I don't think it's a CSS/coding problem. More a rendering problem but I have no idea how to debug it and would like to know what can cause this problem (memory issues, rendering issues etc.) The second image is the image of the ::before when I'm inspecting it, so Chrome **knows** where to render it, but it just doesn't do it correctly.

Comment: If you can't reproduce it, the answer is obvious: the source of the problem is not in the code you're using to reproduce. Take it from large and start reducing until you find the source. If you can't find the rule that interferes by inspecting (which should be trivial), an alternative way to debug is to live disable CSS stylesheets and look at result. When you find the file causing the problem, disable half of it and check again. Than divide in half again, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a redraw issue within Chrome. A heavy animation (fa-spin) from FontAwesome killed the redrawing for the pseudo element.

To get the right redrawing power back to the ::before element I used translate3D trick to get the GPU up to speed for this element.

```
&::before {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the elements in a relative positioned div, thus:
https://jsfiddle.net/qedx9nju/3/

```
<div style="position:relative">


            <label class="mod-form__label" for="email">Email</label>
            <input class="mod-form__input"
                   ng-model="lead.email"
                   id="email"
                   name="email"
                   placeholder="Hierop ontvang je de leads"
                   type="email"
                   ng-class="{ 'error': (quoteForm.email.$invalid && (quoteForm.email.$touched || quoteForm.$submitted)) }"
                   nk-email required="">
            </div>
```

Comment: The "mod-form__container--email" already provides a position relative to the container. As I suggested within the Question, I don't think it's a coding issues.

Comment: They already have a parent. and it's not shared with other elements. They just need `position:relative` on the existing parent, no need to change the markup (which theoretically can stop other CSS rules from applying). They also need `z-index:1` on `::before`, or otherwise it gets covered by the autofill background color, but that's a different issue/detail.

Comment: @Arno, if it already has `position:relative` on the existing parent and it behaves like in your small animation, the problem is with that parent. You can be sure the `::before` is positioned relative to that parent and you need to investigate why the parent behaves like that.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks for your help. I ended up deleting all HTML and added it back in till the problem appeared again. It was a heavy animation of "fa-spin" from FontAwesome that killed the redrawing. So your tips helped allot!